# Keyboard is pushing part of the layout with NestedScrollView and RcyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview, coordinator-layout

I have a layout something like this

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/static_total_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />


        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/static_total_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/slot_selector_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_8"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        tools:itemCount="6" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, the keyboard is pushing the bottom black view (second screenshot). If I remove `RecyclerView` then the keyboard works as expected and the black view is underneath (the first screenshot).
[image]       [image]

I tried the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` .. its not working.

Any help or suggestion! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this programmatically by setting the window soft input mode to `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN`:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```